# Why I catch error when run custom mediator?

Tags: java, apache, wso2

I create basic custom mediator, but it doesn't work.

Steps:

1. Create new Mediator Project in WSO Developer Studio
2. Extend AbstractMediator and implement mediate function

```
package zyatkov;

import org.apache.synapse.MessageContext; 
import org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractMediator;

public class HelloMediator extends AbstractMediator { 

    public boolean mediate(MessageContext context) { 
        // TODO Implement your mediation logic here
        System.out.println("I am custom mediator!!! Hello!!!");
        return true;
    }
}
```

3. Export Project as Deployable Archive.
4. Copy jar file to C:\Programs\WSO2\Enterprise_Integrator\6.4.0\lib
5. Restart wso2 server
6. Add my custom mediator to my Rest API
7. But when I try deploy car application it doesn't start and trow error.

What I do wrong?

```
 org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: API deployment from the file : C:\Programs\WSO2\Enterprise_Integrator\6.4.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1543490054959welltestCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car\welltestAPI_1.0.0\welltestAPI-1.0.0.xml : Failed. at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:219) at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.synapse.SynapseAppDeployer.deployArtifactType(SynapseAppDeployer.java:1065) at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.synapse.SynapseAppDeployer.deployArtifacts(SynapseAppDeployer.java:106) at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager.deployCarbonApp(ApplicationManager.java:272) at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.CappAxis2Deployer.deploy(CappAxis2Deployer.java:72) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:59) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:67) at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.runAxisDeployment(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:93) at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:138) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: API deployment from the file : C:\Programs\WSO2\Enterprise_Integrator\6.4.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1543490054959welltestCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car\welltestAPI_1.0.0\welltestAPI-1.0.0.xml : Failed. at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:207) ... 21 more Caused by: org.apache.synapse.deployers.SynapseArtifactDeploymentException: API deployment from the file : C:\Programs\WSO2\Enterprise_Integrator\6.4.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1543490054959welltestCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car\welltestAPI_1.0.0\welltestAPI-1.0.0.xml : Failed. at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.handleSynapseArtifactDeploymentError(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:480) at org.apache.synapse.deployers.APIDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(APIDeployer.java:71) at org.wso2.carbon.rest.api.ApiDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(ApiDeployer.java:34) at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:197) ... 21 more Caused by: org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Error loading class : zyatkov.HelloMediator - Class not found at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.ClassMediatorFactory.createSpecificMediator(ClassMediatorFactory.java:105) at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AbstractMediatorFactory.createMediator(AbstractMediatorFactory.java:94) at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.MediatorFactoryFinder.getMediator(MediatorFactoryFinder.java:223) at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AbstractListMediatorFactory.addChildren(AbstractListMediatorFactory.java:46) at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.SequenceMediatorFactory.createAnonymousSequence(SequenceMediatorFactory.java:70) at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.rest.ResourceFactory.configureSequences(ResourceFactory.java:107) at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.rest.ResourceFactory.createResource(ResourceFactory.java:50) at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.rest.APIFactory.createAPI(APIFactory.java:88) at org.apache.synapse.deployers.APIDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(APIDeployer.java:47) ... 23 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: zyatkov.HelloMediator cannot be found by synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v80 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:455) at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421) at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412) at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.ClassMediatorFactory.createSpecificMediator(ClassMediatorFactory.java:100) ... 31 more
```